# Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '2 August, 2022' LARAVEL

Tags: laravel

I can not insert date in my project. Can anyone please review my codes to find the error?

in my table--

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('basic_infos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('EmpID');
            $table->string('Emp_Name');
            $table->date('DOB')//date of birth;
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

in my blade file--

```
<input type="date" name="DOB"  id="date_of_birth" class="form-control datepicker form-control-md" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="Date of Birth">
```

in my controller--

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $basicInfo = BasicInfo::create([
            'Emp_name' => $request->Emp_name,
            'DOB' => $request->DOB,
        ]);
    }
```

when I click the save button, then the error
**SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '2 August, 2022' for column..** shows. How do I solve this

Comment: Stop storing dates as text and instead store them in a proper date or datetime column.

Comment: $table->date('DOB') is this incorrect? Can you Explain briefly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse the date from format that your frontend is sending.

This will work in your case:

```php
$dob = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->DOB);
```

If you want to be more strict, validate format on the request first, eg. inline:

```php
$request->validate([
  'DOB' => 'date_format:j m, Y'
]);
```

More on validation:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-date-format

Comment: `public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $basicInfo = BasicInfo::create([
            'Emp_name' => $request->Emp_name,
            'DOB' =>$dob = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->DOB);
        ]);
    }`

Do you mean this?

Comment: yes, no need for `$dob` variable if you put it inline. Have you tried? ;)

Comment: @16_018MD.REAZULHASANRAHI cool! feel free to mark the answer as accepted

Answer (score 2):

use a [mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) in your model  `BasicInfo`.The error thrown because MySQL `DOB` column type `date` expects '`Y-m-d`' format.

```
protected function dob(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        set: fn($value) => Carbon::createFromFormat('d M, Y', $value),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must convert date-time format that match to datatype of DOB in database table

so, try this

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($request->DOB));
```

Hope it helps!